# Conflito na instalação da ultima versão do hive

Tags: flutter, dart

---

EDIT 
Foi corrigido conforme : https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/337

```
This issue is fixed with v1.4.2 update.
1.4.2 -  Fixed dependency issues and minor improvements
```

---

```
dependencies:
  hive: ^1.4.1+1

dev_dependencies:
  hive_generator: ^0.7.0+2
```

> Because hive_generator >=0.6.0 depends on dartx ^0.2.0 which depends
> on quiver >=2.0.3 <2.1.0, hive_generator >=0.6.0 requires quiver >=2.0.3 <2.1.0.
> And because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on quiver
> 2.1.3, hive_generator >=0.6.0 is incompatible with flutter_test from sdk.
>
> So, because app_teste depends on both flutter_test any from sdk and
> hive_generator ^0.7.0+2, version solving failed. pub get failed (1;
> So, because app_teste depends on both flutter_test any from sdk and
> hive_generator ^0.7.0+2, version solving failed.)

Normalmente quando ocorre este tipo de conflito consigo atualizar a versão pelo `pubspec.yamml`, mas desta vez não sei como resolver pois pelo que entendi no erro teria que atualizar `flutter_test`.

Pelo que vi `flutter_test` não atualizado com um package normal.

Como resolver este conflito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa sobrescrever a dependência, colocando o código abaixo em seu pubspec.yaml.

```
dependency_overrides:
  dartx: ^0.4.1
```

Existem tarefas abertas sobre esse problema, e um branch beta, que resolverá o problema quando for lançado a Release. Por enquanto você pode manter esse trecho no seu pubspec.yaml.

[Link da Tarefa no Github](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/247#issuecomment-606838497)

Comment: A maioria dos lugares que encontrei dizia pra usar uma versão que não resolve, ou fazer override em um monte de pacote que ainda dá conflito com o flutter_test. Essa resposta resolveu 100% pra mim. Fiquei surpreso em achar a resposta no stackoverflow em português. Não menosprezando nós falantes da lingua portuguesa, mas como desenvolvedor a gente já está habituado a encontrar tudo em inglês. Vote up com orgulho :)

Comment: Muito obrigado @rneves! Fico feliz em ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

---

EDIT 
Conforme : https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/337

```
This issue is fixed with v1.4.2 update.
1.4.2 -  Fixed dependency issues and minor improvements
```

---

Uma alternativa é fazer um Fork

```
dependency_overrides:
  hive:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/seuusuariogit/hive.git
      path: hive
  hive_generator:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/seuusuariogit/hive.git
      path: hive_generator
```